# How to make com0com ports appear as real physical port?

Tags: virtual-serial-port, com0com

After creating a port pair using com0com, they appear in the com0com section of device manager. A bad behaved application (the source code and developers are not accessible) only list certain ports and calls them 'USB Serial Virtual Ports'.

[HHD Software's](https://www.hhdsoftware.com/virtual-serial-ports) port *does* appear in the bad behaving application's port list, and com0com does not. Can I make com0com virtual ports to appear in the COM/LTP section of device manager? maybe then the bad behaving app would work?

HHD is not open-source. I'd rather use com0com if possible.

Answer (score 1):

After messing around with it I have found that you must install with install portname=COM#

That assigns a realportname, you can then change CNCA0 realportname=COM2 or whatever is open. Where CNCA0 is whatever CNCxx from list you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the "use Ports class" box in the GUI setup?

If the serial ports were given names like COM4 and COM5 then they should appear. If they have names like CNCA0 and CNCB0 then they won't appear.

Comment: I did. The software using the ports was very picky about which ports are physical. In the end I had to use another com port emulator (I guess paid version of com0com which had a trial version?)

Comment: I did notice that the Device Manager doesn't have the "Port Settings" page for com0com virtual ports, so clearly there is some difference apparent to applications; the emulation isn't perfect.

Comment: I have tried for many hours to make COM ports from the com0com available in the list - without success. But inner virtual null modem connection works perfect.